# JQuery tabs won't load

Tags: jquery, tabs

I can't seem to load the tabs on my page. I get an error:

TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

Here is my code:

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.4/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#tabs").tabs();
 });

</script>
```

`
What I am missing?

Comment: Load jquery library  top in order.

Comment: Can you clarify? Which line loads the library? I tried jquery-1.12.4.js first and no dice.

Comment: load `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` on top .Your tab plugin load before  js library so you got that error.

Comment: Thank you, but still getting that error. I am including a headers file (which contains all of the headers) on the page that is loading. Does that change anything?

Comment: I am doing a php include directive which loads the headers for the page so I don't have to include the <head></head> on each page, I just include that file.

Comment: Please see this old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Comment: Use latest and most reliable version of jquery to make it work proper. jquery-1.12.4 is too old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a later version of jQuery.

You could change `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` to:

2x: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>`

3x: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you, but still not working, same error. I must be missing something.

Comment: Figured it out. Was loading an older version of jquery at the end of the page in an included footer file. Thanks all, I appreciate it.

Comment: **Note:** jQuery UI will not support browsers depending on jQuery 1x (IE) because jQuery UI depends on jQuery 2x and higher.